# Java. Retrieve subtree by parent node

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I have tree with the following node spec:

```
java.util.TreeMap<Long id, java.util.TreeMap children>
```

When I fill this map, I would like to retieve subtree only by id.

E.G. 
Tree is:

```
     /-4
   /-2
1 <    /-5
   \-3<
       \-6
```

And when I'm using my code for ID=3, I would like to return only TreeMap with parentNode = 3

Thanks in advice

Comment: A TreeMap is not a Tree data structure. It's a Map datastructure, backed by a tree of comparable keys. I'm not sure to understand how you use this TreeMap to store this tree.

Comment: @JBNizet : I would like to wrap database structure of elements "id,name,name2" to java one. I suppose to store in HasmMap / TreeMap structure. Do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need search algorithm for trees. It's easy with recursion. You should find all children in the root node and call the same method for each of them until you find node with ID you need and return it.
[Here](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html) and [here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-get-example/java-binary-tree-code.shtml) you can find examples. Difference is that you're using a map, but it doesn't matter. Idea is the same.

Comment: It's almost the same. "You should find all children in the root node and call the same method for each of them until you find node with ID you need." read my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need only that subtree? Or all nodes greater than 3? The purpose of the `TreeMap` is to have a sorted map by key, **NOT** to use it as a makeshift tree data structure. It's not even backed by a binary search tree, but by a red-black tree.

To get all nodes with key greater or equal to a given key you can use [TreeMap.TailMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#tailMap%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: I need full subtree:    TreeMap subtree(long id);

Comment: Not what the OP wanted, but interesting topic i wasn't aware of. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general, as long as you tree is not a binary search tree, you must recursively explore the tree (depth-first or breadth-first), and return the node with id equal to the desired value.

I agree that a TreeMap is probably not the best way to implement a binary tree, though.